# Let $X$ be a finite set of $n$ ($>1$) elements and $\tau$ be a topology on $X$ having exactly $m$ elements. Can we give any description of $m$?

Tags: co.combinatorics, gn.general-topology, order-theory, posets

Let $X$ be a finite set of $n$ ($>1$) elements and $\tau$ be a topology on $X$ having exactly $m$ elements.

Can we give any description of $m$ as it relates to $n$?

---

Obviously $2\le m\le 2^n$ and the extreme cases are attained: $m=2$ for the  indiscrete topology and $m=2^n$ for the discrete topology.

---

For $n=2$, $m=2, 3, 4$ are all possible.

For $n=3$, $m=2, 3,\dotsc, 6, 8$ are possible, only $m=7$ isn't possible.

For $n=4$, $m=2, 3,\dotsc, 10, 12, 16$ are possible, $m=11, 13, 15$ aren't possible.

Is it possible to obtain a result similar to Lagrange's theorem in group theory (in a finite group, the order of a subgroup must divide the order of the group)?

Comment: One small comment is that another good way to study finite topological spaces is via their [specialisation preorders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_topological_space#Specialization_preorder). This gives an equivalence of categories to finite preorders, so the question is how many upwards closed sets a preorder on $n$ elements has.

Comment: The paper by Kari Ragnarsson and Bridget Tenner at https://arxiv.org/abs/0802.2550 is relevant.

Comment: [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=2+3+4+2+3+4+5+6+8+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+12+16&go=Search) doesn't know this sequence.

Comment: The paper mentioned by Richard Stanley is _Obtainable sizes of topologies on finite sets_, published as https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jcta.2009.05.002

Comment: Well, the OEIS does describe the sequence alluded to by Richard Stanley: https://oeis.org/A137813